# running a script in c program

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting

I wrote a script to hide user input during runtime it works as a simple script but i want to integrate into c program but it the gives following errors:

```
warning: missing whitespace after macro name

error: expected ')' before '$pass'
```

Here's the program:

```
#include"header.h"
#define SHELLSCRIPT"\
#bin/bash\n\
echo 'Password Please:'\n\
stty -echo\n\
read pass\n\
stty echo\n\
printf'\n'\n\
sleep'2'\n\
echo "$pass"\n\
"
int main()
{
puts("Will execute sh with following script:");
puts("SHELLSCRIPT");
puts("Starting now");
system(SHELLSCRIPT);
return 0;
}
```

if i replace

`echo "$pass" with echo '$pass'` , it runs but prints:

```
Will execute sh with following script

SHELLSCRIPT

Starting now

Password Please:

$pass
```

Instead of $pass at the very last it should print the data entered by the user when prompted at Password Please:

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Don't add unrelated tags and don't add irrelevant information. There is no C code involved here. 2) This looks like a very bad idea with regard to security. Use PAM for user verification!

Comment: Is google or Wikipedia down? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *escape* the characters **"** that surround *$pass*. This should work:

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT"\
#bin/bash\n\
echo 'Password Please:'\n\
stty -echo\n\
read pass\n\
stty echo\n\
printf'\n'\n\
sleep'2'\n\
echo \"$pass\"\n\
"
```

If you you **'** instead of **"** bash will not replace the var-name by its value. See `man bash`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But it still gives warning: missing whitespace after macro name. know what it's about?

Comment: I posted a working version on askubuntu, where you originally asked your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743476/running-script-in-c-program Not sure if necessary to repost here.

Comment: i didn't check the post after you redirected me here. anyway thanks.

Comment: As for the warning, just add a space after the macro name. I also agree with @Olaf, you should use PAM.